# List<> not working properly

Tags: c#, list, events

there is a listView,label which shows the current count of a list called Name, and there is  a event that raise when list count goes beyond 5. but when ever i enter the names in textbox (it goes to the list) it shows the count but the list view is not getting them properly.EX- when i enter the first name label shows the count as 1 and list view shows the name i entered in textbox and WHEN I ENTERED THE SECOND NAME label shows the list counter correctly but list view adds not only the second item i entered but also the first i have enetered before. then there is three items in list view. here is my code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        List<string> emps = new List<string>();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listMake lm = new listMake();

            lm.ListItemAdded += new listMake.listMethods(lm_ListItemAdded);
            lm.adding(emps, textBox1,listView1);
            label1.Text = emps.Count.ToString(); 

        }

        void lm_ListItemAdded(List<string> names)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("it enough i think its  more than 5");

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
    class listMake
    {
        public delegate void listMethods(List<string> names);
        public event listMethods ListItemAdded;

      public  List<string> Name = new List<string>();
        public void adding(List<string>Name,TextBox t1,ListView l1)
        {
            try
            {

                if (t1.Text != "")
                {
                    Name.Add(t1.Text);

                    for (int i = 0; i < Name.Count; i++)
                    {
                        l1.Items.Add(Name[i]);
                    }


                    if (Name.Count > 5)
                        ListItemAdded(Name);
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.StackTrace); ;}
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** You are not clearinig the ListView Items each time you add items from the list.

**Solution 1 :** you need to clear the items from listview before adding into it.

```
        if (t1.Text != "")
        {
            Name.Add(t1.Text);
            l1.Items.Clear(); //add this statement
            for (int i = 0; i < Name.Count; i++)
            {
                l1.Items.Add(Name[i]);
            }


            if (Name.Count > 5)
                ListItemAdded(Name);
        }
```

**Solution 2:** You can add only the item enetered in TextBbox instead of adding all items from begining.so you needto remove the for-loop here.

```
     if (t1.Text != "")
        {
            Name.Add(t1.Text);
            l1.Items.Add(t1.Text);
            if (Name.Count > 5)
                ListItemAdded(Name);
        }
```

Comment: hey thanks Sudhakar it worked, But i don't understand why we need to clear the list before storing in it. because we specify the string in the list by "Name[i] ". then it points to the specific string.

Comment: @user3304413: yes but you are running it in loop so it not only add the current item but it add's items from the begining

Comment: @user3304413: for example you enter "a" in textbox then "a" is added to list first and then all list items (a) are added to listview and ,now enter `b` then `b` is added to `list` first and all items from list(a,b) are added to  listview. so here listview contains item `a` already and also `a` and `b` added from `list`.

Comment: yeah got it loops though the list and adds all of them to the list. thanks alot sudhakar can't vote you up btw have no much reputation